# SocketIO Compatibility

Tags: python, html, flask

I've been trying to implement a chat feature in an app I've made with `Flask` using `SocketIO`. I ran into a problem with the compatibility of my `SocketIO` versions, and eventually found an answer on this site recommending `Flask-SocketIO==4.3.1`, `python-engineio==3.13.2`, and `python-socketio==4.6.0`. I've made the necessary changes, but my console keeps showing an error, saying `ImportError: cannot import name 'run_with_reloader' from 'werkzeug.serving'`. This error was never an issue before, which leads me to believe that my lower version of `SocketIO` is having compatibility issues with whatever werkzeug is. If it's any help, this is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
import os
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('test1.html')
    
@app.route('/login_page')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/home')
@login_required
def home():
    return render_template('test2.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def login_post():
    error = ""
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user and pbkdf2_sha256.verify(password, user.password):
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        else:
            error = "Wrong Username or Password"
            return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        
        existing_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if existing_user:
            return "Username already exists"
    
        hashed_password = pbkdf2_sha256.hash(password)

        new_user = User(username=username, password=hashed_password, email=email)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))

    return render_template('register.html')
    
@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')

def messageReceived(methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('message was received!!!')

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received my event: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Flask_Chat_App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3 style='color: #ccc;font-size: 30px;'>No message yet..</h3>
    <div class="message_holder"></div>

    <method="post" action="/chat">
      <input type="text" class="username" placeholder="User Name"/>
      <input type="text" class="message" placeholder="Messages"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/5.0.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

      socket.on( 'connect', function() {
        socket.emit( 'my event', {
          data: 'User Connected'
        } )
        var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault()
          let user_name = $( 'input.username' ).val()
          let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
          socket.emit( 'my event', {
            user_name : user_name,
            message : user_input
          } )
          $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
        } )
      } )
      socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
        console.log( msg )
        if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
          $( 'h3' ).remove()
          $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
        }
      })
    </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

I tried messing around with the `Werkzeug` package (I don't know what it does; I'm new to this) by installing a lower version (2.0) for the fun of it. After that, my console showed a different error, saying `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'unbound_message'`. I didn't know what else to do, so I just changed Werkzeug back to version 2.3.3. Any ideas on how I should go about fixing this?